# How can i add a character after every word in a string?

Tags: c

So what i have is a string(str) that i get from fgets(str, x, stdin);.
If i write for example "Hello World" i want to be able to add a character infront of each word in the string.

To get this "Hello? World?" as an example. I think i've made it alot harder for myself by trying to solve it this way:

```
add(char *s, char o, char c){
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] != o) {
            s[j] = s[i];
        }
        else {
            s[j] = c;
        }
        j++;
    }
}  

 add(str, ' ','?');
 printf("\n%s", str);
```

This will read out "Hello?World" without the spaces. Now the only way i see this working is if i move everything after the first "?" one to the right while also making the positon of the "W" to a space and a "?" at the end. But for much longer strings i can't see myself doing that.

Comment: Is it okay to write your output to a separate character buffer or does the string have to be modified in-place?  (Writing the modified string to a separate buffer will be easier to implement; if you have to modify the existing string in-place, I suggest doing a separate first pass where you count the number of words in the string, and then do your modification pass backwards, starting at the end if the string and iterating back towards the front)

Comment: It's all okay as long as the output is just like the input except the extra character after every word.

Comment: "*add a character **after** every word*" vs. "*add a character **in front** of each word*" please decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char text[] = "Hello World";

    for(char* word = strtok(text, " .,?!"); word; word = strtok(NULL, " .,?!"))
        printf("%s? ", word);

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4228KB
Hello? World?
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/bFc5JL)

Comment: Why `.,?!` as delimiters?

Answer (score 2):

You can't safely extend a string with more characters without insuring the buffer that holds the string is big enough.  So let's devise a solution that counts how many additional characters are needed, allocate a buffer big enough to hold a string of that length, then do the copy loop.  Then return the new string back to the caller.

```
char* add(const char* s, char o, char c)
{
   size_t len = strlen(s);
   const char* str = s;
   char* result = NULL;
   char* newstring = NULL;

   // count how many characters are needed for the new string
   while (*str)
   {
       len += (*str== o) ? 2 : 1;
       str++;
   }

   // allocate a result buffer big enough to hold the new string    
   result = malloc(len + 1); // +1 for null char

   // now copy the string and insert the "c" parameter whenever "o" is seen
   newstring = result;
   str = s;
   while (*str)
   {
       *newstring++ = *str;
       if (*str == o)
       {
           *newstring++ = c;                
       }
       str++;
  }
  *newString = '\0';

  return result;
}
```

Then your code to invoke is as follows:

```
char* newstring g= add(str, ' ','?');
printf("\n%s", newstring);
free(newstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the amount of storage available when you reach a position where the new character will be inserted, you can check whether the new character will fit in the available storage, move from the current character through end-of-string to the right by one and insert the new character, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

char *add (char *s, const char find, const char replace)
{
    char *p = s;        /* pointer to string */

    while (*p) {                                /* for each char */
        if (*p == find) {
            size_t remain = strlen (p);         /* get remaining length */
            if ((p - s + remain < MAXC - 1)) {  /* if space remains for char */
                memmove (p + 1, p, remain + 1); /* move chars to right by 1 */
                *p++ = replace;                 /* replace char, advance ptr */
            }
            else {  /* warn if string full */
                fputs ("error: replacement will exceed storage.\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
        }
        p++;    /* advance to next char */
    }

    return s;   /* return pointer to beginning of string */
}
...
```

(**note:** the string must be mutable, not a *string-literal*, and have additional storage for the inserted character. If you need to pass a *string-literal* or you have no additional storage in the current string, make a copy as shown by @Selbie in his answer)

Putting together a short example with a `1024-char` buffer for storage, you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

char *add (char *s, const char find, const char replace)
{
    char *p = s;        /* pointer to string */

    while (*p) {                                /* for each char */
        if (*p == find) {
            size_t remain = strlen (p);         /* get remaining length */
            if ((p - s + remain < MAXC - 1)) {  /* if space remains for char */
                memmove (p + 1, p, remain + 1); /* move chars to right by 1 */
                *p++ = replace;                 /* replace char, advance ptr */
            }
            else {  /* warn if string full */
                fputs ("error: replacement will exceed storage.\n", stderr);
                break;
            }
        }
        p++;    /* advance to next char */
    }

    return s;   /* return pointer to beginning of string */
}

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin))
        return 1;

    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
    puts (add (buf, ' ', '?'));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_replace_c
Hello World?
Hello? World?
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's my implementation.  It modifies the string in-place and in O(n) time.  It assumes that the char-buffer is large enough to hold the additional characters, so it's up to the calling code to ensure that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(char *s, char o, char c)
{  
   int num_words = 0;
   char * p = s;
   while(*p) if (*p++ == o) num_words++;

   char * readFrom = p;
   char * writeTo  = p+num_words;
   char * nulByte  = writeTo;

   // Insert c-chars, iterating backwards to avoid overwriting chars we have yet to read
   while(readFrom >= s)
   {  
      *writeTo = *readFrom;
      if (*writeTo == o)
      {  
         --writeTo; 
         *writeTo = c;
      }
      writeTo--;
      readFrom--;
   }

   // If our string doesn't end in a 'c' char, append one
   if ((nulByte > s)&&(*(nulByte-1) != c))
   {  
      *nulByte++ = c;
      *nulByte = '\0';
   }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char test_string[1000] = "Hello World";
    add(test_string, ' ','?');
    printf("%s\n", test_string);
    return 0;
}
```

The program's output is:

```
$ ./a.out 
Hello? World?
```